# Why does pytest not see numpy installation in virtual environment?

Tags: python, pytest, importerror, python-3.8, wsl-2

I have a module that has source code and another folder with a test script.

```
face_zoom
----__init__.py
----face_zoomer.py
----jumpcutter.py
test
----__init__.py
----test.py
```

`face_zoomer.py` and `jumpcutter.py` contain the `FaceZooming` and `Jumpcutter` classes respectively.

The test script calls a simple function in the `face_zoomer.py` file:

```
from face_zoom import FaceZooming

def test_face_zoom:
    [...test function...]
```

The `face_zoomer.py` script imports `JumpCutter`:

```
from .jumpcutter import Jumpcutter
[...other imports...]
[...class definition...]
```

The `jumpcutter.py` script imports numpy:

```
import numpy as np
[...other imports...]
[...class definition...]
```

After entering the virtual environment: `source venv/bin/activate`, and installing numpy: `pip install numpy` (and pip3), then running a pytest: `pytest test/test.py::test_face_zoom -s`:

```
___________________________________ ERROR collecting test/test.py ____________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/mnt/c/Users/wysko/Documents/EditorKH/JC-face/test/test.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
test/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from face_zoom import Jumpcutter, FaceZooming
face_zoom/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from .jumpcutter import Jumpcutter
face_zoom/jumpcutter.py:1: in <module>
    import numpy as np
E   ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Why is it not able to access numpy, or any other non python standard library?

Comment: Probably because `pytest` is not installed in the `venv` env.

Comment: @hoefling Yep, that did it. Thanks!